# How to implemented nested list in XSLT?

Tags: xslt-2.0

I wanted to add `<p>` tag for every `<li>` elements, but there is a special situation when it is a nested list. If there is descendant `<ol>` tag, this adding `<p>` must be closed before this `<ol>` tag. Although it is happened, I could not be able to remove the `<s>test tag</s><br/>`part repetition.

Please help!

Input:

```
<a>
    <ol>
        <li>
            <s>test tag</s><br/>
            <ol>
                <li>list item1</li>
                <li>list item2</li>
                <li>list item3</li>
            </ol>
        </li>
    </ol>
</a>
```

Expected output:

```
<a>
    <ol>
        <li>
            <p><s>test tag</s><br/></p>
            <ol>

                    <p><li>list item1</li></p>
                    <p><li>list item1</li></p>
                    <p><li>list item1</li></p>

            </ol>
        </li>
    </ol>
</a>
```

XSLT code:

```
<xsl:template match="ol">
    <ol>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </ol>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="li[not(descendant::ol)]">
    <li>
        <p>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </p>
    </li>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="li[descendant::ol]">
    <li>
        <p>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[parent::li][following-sibling::ol]"/>
        </p>
    </li>
    <xsl:apply-templates select=""/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node()[parent::li][following-sibling::ol]"/>
```

Comment: Your expected output has "ol" as a child of "ol". Why would you want to do that?

Comment: every <li> tag should be within <p> tag..but if any <li> has decendant <ol> tag that <li> tag should be closed before the decendant <ol> tag..I think it is clear for you @MichaelKay..Thank you

Comment: My comment is no longer relevant, since you have changed the question since I made the comment. But you still seem to be trying to produce invalid HTML: your desired output now has `p` as a child of `ol`. I'm not going to help you produce invalid HTML unless you explain why you want to do so.

Comment: @MichaelKay This is not a actual html page.This is a xml page.Only the concept is list.So I used <li> and <ol> as my input XML file.So I think giving help is not a problem here. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the case where there is no descendant `ol`, your desired output has a p element outside each li, whereas your stylesheet is putting a p inside each ol. I don't know which you actually want, but I assume you know how to fix it.

In the case where there is a descendant `ol`, you have only given one possible example of what you want, and one example does not constitute a specification. However, for that example, the following would work:

```
<xsl:template match="li[ol]">
    <li>
        <p>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::ol)]"/>
        </p>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ol"/>
    </li>
</xsl:template>
```

If this doesn't solve the problem in the general case, that's because you haven't said what's required in the general case.